# Using a WHERE statement with a function parameter inside FORMAT

Tags: postgresql, function, dynamic, format

I'm trying to create a function that will allow me to iterate through a list. It currently takes 2 parameters, st_fips and st_abbr (ex: '01', 'AL'). This function will use `FORMAT` to plug the parameters into a query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pop_allocation_sql.st_fips_updater(
    st_abbr text,
    st_fips text
  )
    RETURNS VOID   
  AS
$$
DECLARE 

BEGIN
 -- logic
 EXECUTE format(
    'UPDATE pop_allocation_output_12102021.%s_population_allocation_20210202
        SET st_fips = %s
        WHERE st_fips <> %s', 
  lower(st_abbr), st_fips, st_fips);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE;
```

The `st_abbr` parameter is unnecessary if I can call that value from another table (a table called `st_fips` that has the name, st_fips, and st_abbr for each state) like this:

```
 SELECT FORMAT('My state abbrevation is %s for st_fips = %s: %s', st_abbr, st_fips, st_fips) FROM geo_context.st_fips WHERE st_fips = '02'
```

How would I plug this into my function so I can just get the `st_abbr` value plugged in base on the `st_fips` parameter?

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Can you explain?